# The impact of relation's direction on performance and how to decide on it

Tags: performance, neo4j, relationship

The [Neo4j documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Relationship.html) says:

> Even though all relationships have a direction they are equally well
>   traversed in both directions so there's no need to create duplicate
>   relationships in the opposite direction (with regard to traversal or
>   performance).

I'm not sure how relations are implemented in Neo4j, but if incoming and outgoing relations are kept in separate sets, even though they are traversed well equally yet how you design your relations can affect the performance.

So I guess my question is, does the direction of a relation affect the performance of a Graph database in a global scheme and if it does, then how should I decide on it? E.g. does keeping the number of incoming and outgoing relations balanced help?

Answer (score 3):

Relationship directionality does not affect performance.

On disk, a node record just keeps a reference to the record for its "first" relationship (either incoming or outgoing). Traversal of relationship paths is done mainly through the relationship records. The full details are too complex to merit discussion here, but relationship data is stored symmetrically with respect to directionality. So, there is no need to worry about balancing relationship directions.

Comment: Could you please expand? E.g. consider you have a node with N relationships. If all of them are outgoing and you are interested in only one of them, doesn't it make it better if half of them were incoming (assuming that you are looking for an outgoing one)? I'm trying to see the performance from a logical point of view, not how Neo4j differentiate between them.

Comment: Thanks, it would be great if you could also include some reference (if possible).